# NSAttributedString throwing an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIFont'"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsattributedstring

I am working on a function with an attributedstring for a label I will use in my application. When I go write my code and run my project I get multiple errors inside that function. It seems that for some reason it showing that "UIFont" and "UIColor" are considered an unresolved identifier. It is confusing me because I have written other functions similar like this in the past and have never had this problem. Here is my code below:

```
  var notificationText: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let timestamp = timestampString else { return nil }
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: user.username,
                                                       attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)])
        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: notificationMessage,
                                                 attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)]))
        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " \(timestamp)", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray]))

        return attributedText
    }
```

Here is a screen shot of the errors it is giving me and where they are located in my code.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This may sound stupid, but did you `import UIKit`?

Comment: Did importing ```UIKit``` resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Stupid mistake by me. Thank you guys sorry about that!